# Scattering in quantum wires

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm working on a project involving scattering of particles in networks of quantum wires off of point scatterers. The problem that I am having is that even in fairly simple configurations of quantum wires there is nontrivial scattering even in the absence of any scatterer. For example, if you consider a T-junction or a single wire with a bend in it there must be an S-matrix just from the particle scattering off of the walls of the wire itself. How can I calculate the transition amplitudes for this kind of scattering?